# Downgrade Mac OSX 12 Monterey to 10.12 Sierra

Tags: macos, downgrade

I bought a refurbished 2015 MacBook so that I could continue using my legacy software, but its SSD came preinstalled with OS 10.14 Monterey. I want to degrade it to 10.12 Sierra. I have a Time Machine / bootable external HD but can't work out how to erase the new SSD and put Sierra on it. I've tried everything, including creating a HFS partition on the SSD, but when I try to run disk utility from the external drive, it doesn't even see the SSD.

EDIT: WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED:

- Booted in recovery mode.
- Booted from Sierra Time Machine backup external drive.
- Booted from a dedicated external Sierra boot drive.
- In all of the above, have tried "Restore", "Install New OS", and "Disk Utility"; in these attempts, the SSD drive doesn't appear as an option.
- I have tried within Monterey, partitioning the new SSD, creating a HFS partition in order to install Sierra on that. This generates error messages that appear to be some kind of incompatibility between Sierra and Monterey. EG, "Error 13" which appears to be some kind of Unix code.
- Or when I choose "Restore" to the new partition, I get the error, "Source volume format on device is not valid for restoring"

The one thing I can think of that I have NOT yet tried is to create a new recovery flash drive apart from the Time Machine backup/boot and the dedicated boot drives that I have. I wanted to do this but when I go to Disk Utility on the old laptop and choose "New Image" - the "Macintosh HD" option is grayed-out.... What's that all about?

- I have read a dozen articles that seem somewhat related, but haven't found one that directly addresses my issue; including https://macmaps.com/docs/DOC-1948/ and https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-10661 and https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-12081

and only turned to this forum in desperation. (I've been using Macs since 1986 and am very comfortable trouble-shooting. I usually can do things myself. I posted to ifixit.com and received only copy-pasted suggestions that I've already tried.)

Clearly there is something fundamentally incompatible between the APFS file system and HFS that's preventing cross-pollination. I just want to get rid of Monterey and get my old Sierra back....

Comment: "I've tried everything" means nothing. Please list every thing you have tried and the research you have done.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the Q with those details.

Answer (score 0):

Someone found the solution to my problem, so I'm posting here in case it might help someone:

*Boot to a High Sierra installer, and the internal drive will be now visible, and you can erase, or do anything else that you need to do with the internal drive.
If you still need to erase the internal drive (and you do need to erase that drive to do what you want with a Sierra system!), then you have to erase the drive with a system newer than Sierra. High Sierra will be successful.
Once the drive is erased (and you have reverted back to a Mac OS Extended format), then you will be able to install Sierra -- followed up with reinstalling Monterey. You will want to decide how much drive space you want for each system. I think you will also realize that you will perhaps struggle when choosing to boot from one system, then the other on the same drive. There would be workarounds to get that to work, too. If you want to have both systems, because of your legacy software, then that will be something that you will have to deal with.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks like further information that should be added to the question, not an answer.